# CPU usage of oracle ASM

Tags: oracle, cpu-usage

How to find how much CPU is being used by oracle ASM. Is there any table which stores the required data ? DO we have predefined table like v$datafiles which contains data related to the datafiles. Is there any other option available for getting the required information.